# Broadcast Receiver not working for voice network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to receive notification when Mobile network connection is lost or received. Through following code, I can receive notification for Wi-Fi (Data) connection but not for Mobile (Voice) connection.

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_ST ATE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
 <receiver android:name=".notifier">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE " />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
</application>
```

Java :

```
public class notifier extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Network Changed !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Please tell me, how can I receive notification for **Mobile Network (Voice)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode！！

```
PhoneStateListener myListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceStateChanged (ServiceState serviceState) {
        // Handle different service states here.
    }
}；

((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE))
    .listen(myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml, first.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

And try this code below.

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mobile = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if(mobile.isConnected()) {
    //Do Sth.
}
```

If this is not work, check your phone's brand. If the phone's developer blocked some codes or not implement some code, it doesn't work. What is your phone?