# How to check if a Android phone has registered to a network or not

Tags: android

TelephonyManager in Android has a few  methods like-
public String getNetworkOperator ()

Availability: Only when user is registered to a network. Result may be unreliable on CDMA networks (use getPhoneType() to determine if on a CDMA network).

**The availability says only when user is registered to a network. 
How can we get a handle to whether there is network or not?**

**Or to put it differently... Even if data access over Mobile Network is disabled how can I check if there is network or not**

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen the broadcast `android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE` and look at the values that it returns:

> int STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY = The phone is registered and locked. Only
> emergency numbers are allowed.
>
> int STATE_IN_SERVICE = Normal operation condition, the phone is registered with an operator either in home network or in roaming.
>
> int STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE = Phone is not registered with any operator,
> the phone can be currently searching a new operator to register to, or
> not searching to registration at all, or registration is denied, or
> radio signal is not available.
>
> int STATE_POWER_OFF = Radio of telephony is explicitly powered off.

See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

Answer (score 0):

Check what is returned if phone is not registered to network. I don't if it returns null while not connected, but that may be answer to your question.

Comment: I'm looking for an event that can be caught when the phone is connected to a network or not

Comment: Try [PhoneStateListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE) and make reciever to get broadcast with state changed.

here is simliar thread on stackoverflow: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381010/broadcast-receiver-not-working-for-voice-network)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to check if there is mobile network even if data access over Mobile Network is disabled